# How can I implement drag and drop of items between 2 listboxes using PowerShell with WPF?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have looked at a good number of tutorials online, but I am in way over my head here.  I just want to be able to drag a listbox item from 1 listbox to another.  There are no examples of how to do this with PowerShell that I can find.  There are examples for how to drag a file from Windows Explorer over to a listbox, but I am not sure how to translate that to what I want.

I have prepared a small example Xaml file to practice with:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxDragDropExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ListBox Drag and Drop Example" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have a function that I pass Xaml through to prepare it for use with PowerShell:

```
function ConvertXaml($inputXML) {
    [hashtable]$return = @{}

    # Modify xaml string so this script understands it
    $inputXML   = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
    [xml]$xaml  = $inputXML
    $XMLReader  = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    $form       = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($XMLReader)

    # Extract object names and assign to variables
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
        $return.($_.Name) = $form.FindName("$($_.Name)")
    }

    $return.form = $form
    Return $return
}
```

And in my code, I call it like this:

```
# Load XAML
$Xaml = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\DragDropExample.xaml"
$gui = ConvertXaml $Xaml

# Show the form
$gui.form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I have tried so many things that don't seem to work, that I am not sure where to even start at this point.  Any guidance/examples of how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming you've already looked through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)?